# Get Property of generic type object without knowing the generic type

Tags: c#, generics, types, properties, get

I need to see a property of an object which is of a generic type, without knowing the specific type:

```
foreach(var n in Nodes)
{
     if(n.GetType().GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(VariableNode<>))
     {
          if((n as VariableNode<>).Variable == myVar) //obviously this does not work
          {
               toRemove.Add(n);
          }
     }
}
```

So, what would be the most elegant way to check the property "Variable" ? (variable is a reference type)

Thanks!

EDIT:

Def of Node:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using UnityEngine;
using KSPComputer.Types;
using KSPComputer.Connectors;
namespace KSPComputer.Nodes
{

    [Serializable]
    public abstract class Node
    {
        public SVector2 Position;
        public int InputCount
        {
            get
            {
                return inputs.Count;
            }
        }
        public int OutputCount
        {
            get
            {
                return outputs.Count;
            }
        }
        public FlightProgram Program { get; private set; }
        private Dictionary<string, ConnectorIn> inputs;
        private Dictionary<string, ConnectorOut> outputs;
        public KeyValuePair<string, ConnectorIn>[] Inputs
        {
            get
            {
                return inputs.ToArray();
            }
        }
        public KeyValuePair<string, ConnectorOut>[] Outputs
        {
            get
            {
                return outputs.ToArray();
            }
        }
        public Node()
        {
            Position = new SVector2();
            inputs = new Dictionary<string, ConnectorIn>();
            outputs = new Dictionary<string, ConnectorOut>();
        }
        internal virtual void Init(FlightProgram program)
        {
            Program = program;
            OnCreate();
        }
        protected void In<T>(string name, bool allowMultipleConnections = false)
        {
            var connector = new ConnectorIn(typeof(T), allowMultipleConnections);
            connector.Init(this);
            inputs.Add(name, connector);
        }
        protected void Out<T>(string name, bool allowMultipleConnections = true)
        {
            var connector = new ConnectorOut(typeof(T), allowMultipleConnections);
            connector.Init(this);
            outputs.Add(name, connector);
        }
        protected void Out(string name, object value)
        {
            ConnectorOut o;
            if (outputs.TryGetValue(name, out o))
            {
                if (o.Connected)
                {
                    o.SendData(value);
                }
            }
        }
        protected ConnectorOut GetOuput(string name, bool connected = true)
        {
            ConnectorOut o;
            if (outputs.TryGetValue(name, out o))
            {
                if (o.Connected || !connected)
                {
                    return o;
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
        protected ConnectorIn In(string name)
        {
            ConnectorIn o;
            if (inputs.TryGetValue(name, out o))
            {
                return o;
            }
            return null;
        }
        public void UpdateOutputData()
        {
            RequestInputUpdates();
            OnUpdateOutputData();
        }
        protected virtual void OnUpdateOutputData()
        { }
        protected virtual void OnCreate()
        { }
        protected void RequestInputUpdates()
        {
            foreach (var i in inputs.Values)
            {
                i.FreshData = false;
            }
            foreach (var i in inputs.Values)
            {
                if (!i.FreshData)
                {
                    i.RequestData();
                }
            }
        }
        public IEnumerable<Connector> GetConnectedConnectors()
        {
            return (from c in inputs.Values where c.Connected select c as Connector).Concat(from c in outputs.Values where c.Connected select c as Connector);
        }
        public IEnumerable<Connector> GetConnectedConnectorsIn()
        {
            return (from c in inputs.Values where c.Connected select c as Connector);
        }
        public IEnumerable<Connector> GetConnectedConnectorsOut()
        {
            return (from c in outputs.Values where c.Connected select c as Connector);
        }
    }
}
```

Definition of VariableNode:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using KSPComputer;
using KSPComputer.Nodes;
using KSPComputer.Connectors;
using KSPComputer.Variables;
namespace KSPComputer.Nodes
{
    [Serializable]
    public class VariableNode<T> : ExecutableNode
    {
        internal Variable Variable { get; private set; }
        internal void SetVariable(Variable variable)
        {
            this.Variable = variable;
        }
        protected override void OnCreate()
        {
            In<T>("Set");
            Out<T>("Get");
        }
        protected override void OnExecute(ConnectorIn input)
        {
            Variable.Value = In("Set").Get<T>();
            ExecuteNext();
        }
        protected override void OnUpdateOutputData()
        {
            Out("Get", Variable.Value);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide some more context around that code? I would have suggested a generic type constraint ... but without more context I am unsure if that is appropriate.

Comment: Generic type constraints are not applicable unfortunately. What would you like to see ?

Comment: The definitions of `Node` and `VariableNode<>` would be good.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you should be able to use reflection:

```
foreach(var n in Nodes)
{
     if(n.GetType().GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(VariableNode<>))
     {
          if(n.GetType().GetProperty("Variable").GetValue(n, null) == myVar) 
          {
               toRemove.Add(n);
          }
     }
}
```

Comment: That compiles. Out of interest, why does GetValue need n as a parameter even though it's called on a property of n already ? (PS: testing will take a while, I will add the answer as correct as soon as I can confirm it!)

Comment: @pixartist It's because you're getting an object of type `PropertyInfo` which knows nothing about the object it was called on. `GetValue` says "Get the value of this property from this instantiated object of the type".

Answer (score 0):

The other solution would be defining a non-generic base class for your VariableNode  then you can put your non-generic property there, and finally you can easily cast   your node as the base or interface and get the value of your property. Having a non generic base is quite popular practice.

Comment: Yes, I thought about that, but that would make calling the generic methods a pain in the *** (In<T>, Out<T> and Get<T>). Edit: Ah okay, yes non generic BASE class. Yeah, but that would complicate things in this case. I prefer the reflection method here.